# open new window as a dialog (Qt4)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I created a main window and new window. when a button is pressed on the main window the new window will appear. thats all right. but I need the new window to apper as a dialog. that means whan a dialog is opened the main window will not function untill the dialog is closed. and when a dialog is opened a new tsb will not apper in the taskbar. how to do this.

here are some codes what i used,

mainwindow.h

```
 private:
  Form *myform;

public slots:
 void myformshow();
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
mainWin::mainWin(QWidget *parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
 connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(myformshow()));
}

  void mainWin::myformshow(){
myform= new Form(); //make sure to delete newform someware.
myform->show();
}
```

form.h

```
 class Form : public QWidget, private Ui::Form
{
 Q_OBJECT

public:
 Form(QWidget *parent);

public slots:
void  command();
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

here Form means, I created the new window as `forms.h` and its class is `Form`

Comment: See http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdialog.html#exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the second window inherit from QDialog (not strictly necessary, but will give you correct platform-specific behavior, like centering and various window flags), set the main window as its parent, and run it using its `exec()` function.

First, change your Form class to inherit from QDialog:

```
class Form : public QDialog, private Ui::Form
```

(If you had references to QWidget elsewhere in your From class code, change them too.)

Then, in your mainWin::myformshow() function, do:

```
void mainWin::myformshow()
{
    myform = new Form; //make sure to delete newform someware.
    myform->exec();
}
```

Comment: I added my form.h file sourse also. now can you please tell me how to add the cord.

Comment: @LakshanPerera You forgot to `#include <QDialog>`.

Comment: thats ok now. i get a error in this line  `myform = new Form();` the error is `error: no matching function for call to 'Form::Form()'`

Comment: when I remove this line it compiles without errors. but when try to open the new window it crashes.

Comment: @LakshanPerera: Your constructor requires a `QWidget` parameter. Either provide the parameter, i.e. `myForm = new Form(this);`, or make the parameter optional, `Form(QWidget *parent = NULL);`

Comment: @LakshanPerera: Judging by the questions you are asking, you really might want to pick up a C++ primer of some sort. I'm not saying that to be mean, just saying that using Qt effectively assumes a certain degree of familiarity with C++, and the questions you are asking are pretty fundamental concepts.

Comment: @DaveMateer thank you very mutch. it worked. im very new to Qt. by the time still im learning c++. but i like to learn qt also. so I started it also. when Im finished studing c++ I will understand these concepts.

Comment: this worked. but when the dialog opened it starts another tab in the taskbar. why is that. is there a method to prevent it. (ex: in firefox tools->options will not creat a new tab)

Comment: Another option that is possible instead of calling exec is to create the dialog using new(), set it as modal, and then show it.  This is often better than creating a new event loop using exec.

Comment: @LakshanPerera There are various options that can affect dialog behavior.  See the documentation for QWidget::windowFlags.

Comment: Always go through the documentation http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdialog.html#QDialog 

Qt has a perfectly organized documentation, use them